# Using a python script to print to Chrome console - how to tweak to print in a div?

Tags: javascript, python, html

Doing some early testing to run a Python script in a Chrome extension. The following works but I need help figuring out how to show the value in a div instead of printing to console. Wasn't able to find any syntax help through Google.

Here is the Python:

```
from browser import document

def echo(*args):
    print("Hello {}!".format(document["zone"].value)) //This prints to console. 

document["test"].bind("click", echo)
```

Here's the HTML, which calls the python:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://brython.info/src/brython.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body onload="brython()">
      <script type="text/python" src = "hello.py"></script>
      <p>Your name is: <input id="zone" autocomplete="off">
         <button id="test">click!</button>

      <div>Show value here</div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where will you like to show this value?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I've edited my question to insert a placeholder div where I'd like it to live. Formatting is irrelevant this is just testing for future dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `div` that is sibling with `p` using CSS selector.

Then, bind a event listener to input and change the div text to reflect the input change.

```
<script type="text/python">
from browser import document 

div = document.get(selector='body p + div')[0]

def input(ev):
    div.text = ev.target.value

document['zone'].bind('input', input)
</script>
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for the help.